# Make Touch Bar Esc key "click"

Tags: applescript, development, touch-bar

Is there a way to make the Touch Bar <kbd>esc</kbd> key emit a "click" sound when it is pressed? This way I'd have some feedback that I successfully pressed the button when using vim.

I'd be happy with an Apple Script, or whatever works.